# Globbing pattern to exclude files in directory, but include subdirectories

Tags: glob

I have the following file hierarchy:

```
scripts
    someConfigFile.js
    anotherConfigFile.js

    someModuleDirectory
        someModule.js

    anotherModuleDirectory
        anotherModule.js

        subDirectory
            thirdModule.js
```

I want to match all the files in the module directories, but excude the config files contained in the `scripts` directory itself, using [Glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob):

```
var glob = require('glob');

console.log(glob.sync(unknownGlobPattern));
```

Required output (unordered):

```
[
    'someModuleDirectory/someModule.js',
    'anotherModuleDirectory/anotherModule.js',
    'anotherModuleDirectory/subDirectory/thirdModule.js'
]
```

Comment: I found a solution using Karma `excludes` in config file, so I rephrased this question to be more specific.

Answer (score 11):

The following glob should work:

`['./scripts/**/*', '!./scripts/*']`

First part will include all files in all subdirectories. Second part will exclude files in starting directory.

Comment: hi, i have a similar issue when need to include it all into one "command" due to usage in CLI

Comment: Doesn't work, glob constructor takes input parameter as string and callback.

Comment: @Trishant Pahwa where is the question do you something about constructor or its parameters? The question is about globbing pattern, it is up to you adjust it for your use case.